# Dynamic Graph Visualisation Using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, cytoscape.js, sigma.js

I would like to visualize a dynamic graph. Actually, I take a look on how some libraries treating that like `d3.js`, `sigma.js` and  `cytoscape.js`. The problem is that these libraries are reading the graph data from a specific file, in my case these data will be generated using a program (dynamically).

I am wondering if I can replace the file data, by a string text containing all information ?

Comment: I would suggest reading the documentation more carefully. Examples might show reading static files, but that does not mean it is the only way to do it.

Comment: There are certainly examples of D3 being used with in-line data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about those 3, but I use Highcharts for stuff like this. I believe [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax) showcases something like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using `cytoscape.js` and all of my graph information is generated based on parsing user input, everything from click events to dropdown menu selection to text input.

I do not know that you can just replace an input file with a string and have it do the work for you, but if you know what to expect from the string input then you should be able to parse it to look like you want it to.

Comment: I think that the 'cy.add(element)' of cytoscape is usefull, so i can add data element dynamically which i didn't found with d3.js